# Invoke different methods if a Codename One Button receives a short tap or a long tap

Tags: codenameone

I need to implement a Codename One Button enough "smart" to invoke different methods if it's tapped for a short time or for a long time. How can I achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Button b = new Button() {
    private long pressTime;
    public void pressed() {
       pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    public void released(int x, int y) {
       if(System.currentTimeMillis() - pressTime > LONG_TAP_TIME) {
          longTap();
       } else {
          shortTap();
       }
    }
};
```