# longPointerPress() not called for (most?) components

Tags: codenameone

I noticed that `longPointerPress` is not called for Label derivates.

Therefore I created some code to investigate further when `longPointerPress()` is called and was surprised that:

- `Label` derivates do receive pointer events - however no `longPointerPress`
- `Button` derivates do receive pointer events and `longPointerPress` just works
- `TextField` derivates do receive pointer events unless editing, then they eat all the pointer events.

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to have various components in a `Container` and still be able to get notified for `longPointerPress` events under all circumstances.

How can I achieve this?

Here is the code - do a long tap on all the components and watch the console:

```
public class FormLongPointerPress extends Form {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private interface With<T> {
        void act(T ... aTs);
    }

    public FormLongPointerPress() {
        super("FormLongPointerPress");
        setScrollableY(true);
        setLayout(BoxLayout.y());
        With<Component> with = (aComponents) -> {
            Container container = FlowLayout.encloseCenter(aComponents);
            container.addPointerPressedListener((aActionEvent) -> Log.p("container.pointerPressed(" + aActionEvent.getX() + ", " + aActionEvent.getY() + ")"));
            container.addPointerReleasedListener((aActionEvent) -> Log.p("container.pointerReleased(" + aActionEvent.getX() + ", " + aActionEvent.getY() + ")"));
            container.addLongPressListener((aActionEvent) -> Log.p("container.longPress(" + aActionEvent.getX() + ", " + aActionEvent.getY() + ")"));
            for (Component component: aComponents) {
                component.addPointerPressedListener((aActionEvent) -> Log.p("component.pointerPressed(" + aActionEvent.getX() + ", " + aActionEvent.getY() + ")"));
                component.addPointerReleasedListener((aActionEvent) -> Log.p("component.pointerReleased(" + aActionEvent.getX() + ", " + aActionEvent.getY() + ")"));
                component.addLongPressListener((aActionEvent) -> Log.p("component.longPress(" + aActionEvent.getX() + ", " + aActionEvent.getY() + ")"));
            }
            getContentPane().add(container);
        };
        with.act();
        with.act(new Label("A Label"));
        with.act(new Button("A Button"));
        with.act(new TextField("A TextField"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the text. My observations were partly wrong

Comment: I'm using this approach suggested by Shai: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52360458/2670744

Comment: try `setFocusable(true)`

Comment: I tried `setFocusable(true)` which works for `Label`derivates but has side effects like different styling. Perhaps adding a longPressListener to the `Form` would be an effective way of getting notified of a long press without much side effects. Is there a good reason why long press is not processed for non-focusable components?